# SharePoint Online REST: Search vs accessing list directly

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

so I have been to a sharepoint on premise training some time ago. I just recently started developing an app for sharepoint online. I do remember the tutor saying that it would be better to query the search api instead of sending requests querying the list directly. Apparently it has something to do with the indexes, so all in all it would be faster and save ressources.
Now I am on SharePoint Online. Ressources are no problem, I suppose.

Is there any reason to send ajax requests to the sharepoint search api instead of calling the rest calls for a list? The data I would like to query is inside the the same site collection as my app. When to use what? Unfortunately I could not find a comparison. I'd be thankful if anybody with a deeper understanding can give some insights.

Thank you very much.